# Angular 9. Component is class of Sample but not SampleExtended despite it was created as SampleExtended

Tags: angular, class

I have a component in Angular:

```
class Sample implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
     // does something here
}
```

Then I created an extended class:

```
class SampleExtended extends Sample {
      change() {return true;}
}
```

When I call change function from Sample Extended it throws error that change is not a function.

And when i console log the component it shows it as object Sample instead of SampleExtended.

Here is where i call console.log(). It is in beforeEach block where i get it from TestBed:

```
let fixture: ComponentFixture<SampleExtended>, 
component: SampleExtended, 
el: DebugElement, 
cfr: any, 
cdr: any, 
elementRef: ElementRef;

beforeEach(async(() => {

    const cfrSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ComponentFactoryResolver', [
        'resolveComponentFactory'
    ]);

    const cdrSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ChangeDetectorRef', [
        'detectChanges'
    ]);

    const elementRefMock = {};

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            SampleExtended,
            { provide: ComponentFactoryResolver, useValu: cfrSpy },
            { provide: ChangeDetectorRef, useValue: cdrSpy },
            { provide: ElementRef, useValue: elementRefMock },
            { provide: ELEMENT_COMPONENTS, useValue: {} }
        ]
    }).compileComponents().then(() => {

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SampleExtended);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        el = fixture.debugElement;

        console.log(component);

        cfr = TestBed.inject(ComponentFactoryResolver);
        cdr = TestBed.inject(ChangeDetectorRef);
        elementRef = TestBed.inject(ElementRef);

    });

}));
```

Does anybody know how can i fix it?

Comment: Where is `change` function defined and where is your `console.log()`? can you update your post :)

Comment: Sorry, I am new in Angular. Change function is defined in SampleExtended. I will update post where I call console.log in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend an Angular Component, you have to do it the proper way :

```js
export class SampleExtended extends Sample implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy
...
```

You also have to inject whatever you use in the base class constructor using `super` in your inherited class.

```js
constructor(...) {
    super(...);
}
```

Inherited component have they own templates and styles but are Angular components, therefore they have to be declared in one of your app Angular Modules, and have the `@Component` decorator.